# DataTables.net colvis: The list of available fields won't go away on losing focus

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using DataTables.net (1.10.12) in my ASP.NET MVC web application with server-side processing (table loads, no problems with the data or controller). When I add the colvis button, I get the list of available fields and I can select and deselect the columns I want.

The problem comes in when I'm done selecting or deselecting fields - the list doesn't fade away on losing focus.

What am I missing?

here's my view:

```html
<table class="table" id="tblMyIndex">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field_A</th>
            <th>Field_B</th>
            <th>Field_C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#tblMyIndex').dataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            deferRender: true,
            stateSave: true,
            dom: 'lfBtipr',
            buttons: ['colvis'],
            ajax: {
                "url": "/MyController/MyAction",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            columns: [
                { "data": "Field_A" },
                { "data": "Field_B" },
                { "data": "Field_C" }
            ],
            order: [[0, "asc"]]
        });
    });
</script>
```

when I look at the error captured in chrome, it says the following (not sure if that's meaningful to anybody):

```html
Uncaught TypeError: d(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function
at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.min.js:24)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
at HTMLBodyElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

Answer (score 0):

welp, there was nothing wrong with my view - apparently datatables 1.10.12 and jQuery 3.1.0+ have issues. Specifically DataTables' buttons plugin below version 1.2.2 may have issues. Updated to datatables 1.10.13 with buttons 1.2.2 and all was well...

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36825/problem-with-jquery-3-1-0